# Reorder several fieldcontainer with drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

Is it possible in a form to reorder (vertically) several fieldcontainer with drag and drop?

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1rq5

**EDITED:**

I edited my fiddle with configs draggable:true and contrain:true.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/api/Ext.form.FieldContainer.html#cfg-draggable

It seems to me to be the right way to go.

However, I have not yet been able to get a 'coordinated' drag and drop so that the fields maintain a fixed distance between them and prevent the fields overlapping. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I edited my question and fiddle.

Comment: What you are doing right now is enable dragging floating components freely, but not a "drag and drop" of non-floating components, which is what you want to achieve. For DD, I strongly believe you have to add a [`DragSource`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.dd.DragSource.html) and a [`DropTarget`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.dd.DropTarget.html) to the parent container of the items you wish to order using drag/drop.

Comment: Thanks Alexander.